# why printf is not printing only the ini string?

Tags: c

I need to copy the "ini" string to the "final" string inverting the character order, but when i print the string "ini" it appears to print "ini" and "final" together.

Language: C

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(){
    char ini[10]={'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j'};
    char final[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10 ; i++) {
        final[i]=ini[10-1-i];
    }
    printf("%s\n\n",ini);
    printf("%s",final);
}
```

My output is:

```
abcdefghijjihgfedcba

jihgfedcba
```

But it should be this:

```
abcdefghij

jihgfedcba
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Strings require a null terminator.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(){
    char ini[11]={'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j', 0};
    char final[11];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10 ; i++) {
        final[i]=ini[10-1-i];
    }
    final[10] = 0;
    printf("%s\n\n",ini);
    printf("%s",final);
}
```

If you use a string literal as the initializer, it includes the terminator automatically. The following is equivalent:

```
char ini[] = "abcdefghij";
```